# Changing the child element of Gutenberg image block

Tags: javascript, wordpress-gutenberg, gutenberg-blocks

I want to change the child element of Gutenberg image block. In code below I need to change the class of img element (wp-image-10).

```
<figure class="wp-block-image">
    <img src="http://localhost:8888/img.jpg" class="wp-image-10"/>
</figure>
```

Which hook or filter should I use to reach the child element most effectively?